# Generate 100% custom layer2 payload with python / scapy

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, wifi

I want to create a python3 script which uses a wireless active connection (the bssid which the interface is attached at the moment) to send a 100% custom layer 2 payload (or in other words, a 100% custom layer 3 or 2.5 protocol).

I have tried a lot of ways with scapy, with scripts like the following:

```
from scapy.all import *
import os

interfaces = os.listdir('/sys/class/net')
interface = interfaces[1] # which is the wireless interface

send(Dot11(addr1 = 'aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa'), iface = str(interface)) # I pretend here to send an empty frame to addr1 destination, using the wireless card and the existing bssid on which i'm currently connected
```

Always I get the destination MAC address as broadcast. And of course I don't understand the proper way to do what I want.

Any suggestion or clarification is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, the key is use sendp instead send, for example a IEEE1905 Ethertype:

```
import os
from scapy.all import *

dest_MAC = aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa # the mac address you want to send it

interfaces = os.listdir('/sys/class/net') interface = interfaces[3] #select one interface from the array, it could be Ethernet or an existing Wireless STA connection

p = Ether(type=0x893a, dst = dest_MAC)/b"\x00\x00\x00" #we send just three "zero" bytes

sendp(p, iface=interface) #using sendp instead send, which is layer2 abstracted
```